Hard forks compatibility
I understood that an hard forks is a non backward compatible version of the protocol.
I read a bit about previous forks and EIP implemented but there is still a thing that I don't understand.
Every hardfork just added modification that didn't broke past committed transactions/smart contract?
What i mean is: If i create a smart contract with certains rules/opcodes etc, can a new future version of the protocol invalidate my contract?
It's possible such a scenario so it would be needed to deploy a new version of the contract or every contract will be valid forever?

While a hard fork can potentially invalidate existing smart contracts, the Ethereum community has developed strategies to minimise the impact of such changes.
But still, it’s possible that a new version of the protocol could introduce changes that invalidate certain smart contracts. These changes could be related to opcodes, gas costs, or other protocol-level adjustments. In such cases, you may need to deploy new versions of your contracts to ensure compatibility with the updated protocol.
Also, in order to avoid such invalidations on hard forks, you can deploy new contracts using forward-compatible versions of the EVM to ensure their longevity and security in the face of future protocol upgrades.
This article might be helpful.

what happens if I call an uncompatible smart contract after an hard
fork then? There are examples of that?

After the Istanbul hard fork, some smart contracts experienced issues (like this) due to changes in gas costs or opcode behaviour. For example, contracts that relied heavily on certain opcodes or gas calculations may have encountered unexpected behaviour or failures after the fork.

what happens if I call an uncompatible smart contract after an hard fork then? There are examples of that?

Added the response to this, in the answer.
